# Primefaces encoding of & instead of &amp;

Tags: java, primefaces

Hi I am using PrimeFaces Autocomplete to display a list of business names. The business names are held in an Oracle Database. The problem is that for a business name, like B & Q,  autocomplete displays the & as `&amp;` for example 
B & Q.
I tried using a URLDecoder method with business.getBusinessName() as the string and was having no success. Any suggestion on how to resolve this HTML encoding problem?
Thanks
Bryce

Comment: Try replacing it by `\u0026` and see what happens

Comment: Please post Pf version?

Comment: Apologies.
The PrimeFaces version is 5.2.1 
Thanks
Bryce

Comment: Managed to use the word "and" instead of the ampersand symbol using the following code.                                                                                              businessNameCapitalized.setDisplayName(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(businessNameCapitalized.getBusinessName()).replaceAll("\\B&\\B", "and"));

Answer (score 0):

Managed to use the word "and" instead of the ampersand symbol using the following code. Not ideal but it is a workaround.

businessNameCapitalized.setDisplayName(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(businessNameCap‌​italized.getBusinessName()).replaceAll("\B&\B", "and"));

Comment: It should be "\\B&\\B"